# Can I combine two and more classes which have common properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, casting

I have a CheckBox and a HtmlInputCheckBox. These are Checked property is common. I want to get  value of checked property. **I will do to with using reflection, but I want not to use reflection.** example code this way,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxHtml" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox" runat="server" />
```

These are in gridview.

I can find them with using FindControl in gridview, but FindControl Return Type is Control.
So I need to use Cast for get checked value. The Control I want to access can be different type. For example, CheckBox or HtmlInputCheckBox etc.. Therefore, I want to do casting with using one type.

I thought this way,

```
public interface ICommonClass
{
    bool GetChecked();
}

public class NewCheckBox:CheckBox,ICommonClass
{
    public bool GetChecked()
    {
        return Checked;
    }
}

public class NewHtmlInputCheckBox:HtmlInputCheckBox,ICommonClass
{
    public bool GetChecked()
    {
        return Checked;
    }
}

var obj = (ICommonClass)gridview.FindControl("checkbox");
var obj = (ICommonClass)gridview.FindControl("checkboxHtml");

obj.GetChecked();
```

This code don't run. Because it gives error when it make to cast. The correct one, this already :) I gave this example for I tell my thought. Such a thing can be done?

Comment: Make GetChecked abstract so every derived class needs to derive a GetChecked method (only improvement, not a solution to the problem).

Comment: FindControl probably returns some type ... you need to derive ICommonClass with the same type as the return type of FindControl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't bother with all that. Just write a simple extension method that checks the type of the control and casts as appropriate, e.g.

```
public static class ControlHelpers {
    public static bool GetChecked(this Control ctrl) {
        if(ctrl is CheckBox) {
            return ((CheckBox) ctrl).Checked;
        } else if(ctrl is HtmlInputCheckBox) {
            return ((HtmlInputCheckBox) ctrl).Checked;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Some sort of CheckBox is required here.");
        }
    }
}
```

you can then use it like this:

```
bool checked = gridview.FindControl("checkbox1").GetChecked();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are new controls, these need to be registered in [web.config or at the page level](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx). Then you can use them in the pages.

```
<myPrefix:NewCheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox" />
<myPrefix:NewHtmlInputCheckBox runat="server" ID="checkBoxHtml" />
```

Then you can use their interface

```
var checkbox = (ICommonClass)gridview.FindControl("checkbox");
var checkBoxHtml = (ICommonClass)gridview.FindControl("checkBoxHtml")
var checked1 = checkbox.GetChecked();
var checked2 = checkBoxHtml .GetChecked();
```

The CheckBox type can't be casted to ICommonClass interface, because this type doesn't implement it, but the new type NewCheckBox does. The GridView will contain controls of this this new type to benefit ICommonClass.

Comment: the interfaces are ok but I getting error due to cast. Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' to type 'ICommonClass'.